# Ceiling fan light went off completely and now it blinks one short blink and comes on okay

Tags: ceiling-fan

Ceiling light went out completely and I turned off at the wall and it did it again.  I changed the bulbs (4) 60 watts.  Now it blinks one short blink when I turn the unit on at the wall and comes on okay.

Comment: What vintage is this ceiling fan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overloading it.  It is probably listed for 40W bulbs.  Switch some of the bulbs to LEDs.

It may be best to keep one incandescent; some electronic modules do not like it when they are all LEDs.

Since you *just bought* incandescents, I assume you have been put off by the ugly, dazzling blue of the early LED attempts. *You and everyone else*. They are much better now.  While it's always possible to buy cheap junk, any reasonable quality of LED allows your choice of color temperature from 5000K LED dazzle-blue, clear down to 2700K traditional incandescent.

What they're selling you now as "incandescents" are in fact **halogens**, which still incandescent but with a trick for efficiency (not much).  It is also bluer (not much) so its light is 3000K - keep that in mind if matching.

Cheapie LEDs tend to be 5000k because it's cheaper to make. Cheapies also tend to have terrible CRI, meaning the various colors are all lop-sided - too much blue, no green, etc.  If CRI is specified, aim for 80% or above. If it's not specified, *lookout!*   Actually 5000K does have its uses (it matches daylight) but nobody wants bad CRI.

Comment: Last bulbs I purchased were 60 watt and not 40 watt as recommended for the ceiling fan light.  My wife says I never look at instructions.  I took a couple of the bulbs out and there is no more quick blink before the light comes on.  I am now on my way to buy the 40 watts so thanks a million.